# using conditional operation in for loop

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I need to skip certain part of the code if condition is true, How to do it in php

```
   if ($a==0 && $b==0)
     {

//skip this part of the code and exit loop 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`break;`](http://php.net/break) to exit from a loop.

Example:

```
<?php
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'stop', 'five');
while (list(, $val) = each($arr)) {
    if ($val == 'stop') {
        break;    /* You could also write 'break 1;' here. */
    }
    echo "$val<br />\n";
}
```